# How to limit number of threads at particular interval?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

My query is I have a method that should be called at a particular interval with specific number of threads at that interval and then stay idle after its next call.

To be more clear on it, I have presented a sample code below:

```
namespace ThreadTest
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         Initialize Components();
      }
   }

   public void ExtractDatafromWebPage()
   {
      //Code for extracting data from web page using HTTPWebRequest and HTTPWebResponse class
   }

   private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     // On clicking the button the ExtractDatafromWebPage() method should be called with 5 threads at every 10 seconds.
   }
}
```

Now my requirement is the method should be called after every 10 seconds and at a time only 5 threads should be associated with this method and should stay idle until next 10 seconds. This process will keep on continuing infinitely.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar as shown below, if I understand your question correctly (as I am not sure what you mean by: *'only 5 threads should be associated with this method'*)

And if you mean only five threads should enter the method, then just have a semaphore with count '5'.

pass in the number of threads you need to spawn, time period etc.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // On clicking the button the ExtractDatafromWebPage() method should be called with 5 threads at every 10 seconds.
            Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                    {
                        //you can use thread pool thread
                        new Thread(() => this.ExtractDatafromWebPage()).Start();
                    }
                }, null, 0, 10 * 1000);
        }
```